# how to implement ng-handsontable lazy loading for angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, handsontable

I am working on an angularJS project where i have met with a requirement to implement ng-handsontable lazy loading feature. The data is huge such that if allowed to display all at once will make the site very slow.
Is there any way to implement the lazy loading feature for ng-handsontable for angularJS.

I have tried using the pure javascript to implement it, but not working for angularjs.

Html code is:

```
<div id="example1" class="hot handsontable htRowHeaders htColumnHeaders">
</div>
```

Javascript code is:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

// mock service for getting data
var fetchData = function(n) {
return Handsontable.helper.createSpreadsheetData(n, 3);
};
// variables
var example = document.getElementById('example1');
var hot;
var data = fetchData(100);  
var compute_window = function(e) {
var rowCount = hot.countRows();
var rowOffset = hot.rowOffset();
var visibleRows = hot.countVisibleRows();
var lastRow = rowOffset + (visibleRows * 1);
var lastVisibleRow = rowOffset + visibleRows + (visibleRows/2);
var threshold = 15;

if(lastVisibleRow > (rowCount - threshold)) {
  loadMoreData(rowCount);
}
};

// initialize HOT
hot = new Handsontable(example,{
data: data,
rowHeaders: true,
colHeaders: true,
afterScrollVertically: compute_window
});

// load data and render
var loadMoreData = function(n) {
// call data service
  var incoming = fetchData(n);
incoming.forEach(function(d) {
    data.push(d);
});
hot.render();
};
});
```

Anybody please help.
Thanks

Comment: I think `ngHandsontable` is having pagination feature, Keep try using that. It might help.

Comment: thanks for the reply @Samir but i dont want the pagination feature, just wanted to load in a single page but with lazy loading.